# From PHP to vb.net; How to transfer a text from one page to another in Visual Basic Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

so I am a web developer who is used to PHP and MySQL and now my company is switching completely to VB.Net. I am using Visual Studio 2010 for development.

How would best would I accomplish displaying the text from one page sent using a GET method of a form on a different page?

What I would like to do is:

Page 1, have a list of buttons, and depending on which button I click a name is sent to the next page.

Page 2 receives the name and displays the name in a textbox or some other form field.

Also, any resources that might help me quickly learn the ins and outs of vb.net.

I am familiar with Visual basic and have coded in it before, but never in a .net environment.

Thanks!

Comment: there's no real trick to that , If you want to display a specific string from a GET request from an aspx page then you are just going to do it like any other language, query string or session or cookie

Comment: @ScottSelby, I have found that to be the case. My problem is finding the correct syntax and rules relating to the best way of putting the string accessed into a field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on first page

```
<a href="OtherPage.aspx?Parameter=myParameter" >
```

then in the code behind for OtherPage.aspx in Page_Load

```
Dim query as String = Request.QueryString("Parameter")
myLabel.Text = query
```

in the XHTML in OtherPage.aspx you would see

```
<asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read some examples here

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5876/Passing-variables-between-pages-using-QueryString

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/10/query-string-in-aspnet-example-c-vbnet.html?m=1